# R Loop and Matrices

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to get this simple 'for loop' to work. I can't get dim(F4) to be a 6848x2 matrix. I just want to divide the row entries of two matrices. Here's what I have...

```
             > dim(F3)
          [1] 6848    2

      > head(F3)
     [,1]     [,2]
      [1,] 140.9838 516.0239
      [2,] 140.9838 516.0239
      [3,] 140.9838 516.0239
      [4,] 140.9838 516.0239
      [5,] 140.9838 516.0239
      [6,] 175.5093 515.2280
      > dim(scale)
      [1] 6848    1

      F4 <- matrix(, nrow = nrow(F1), ncol = 1)
      for (i in 1:t){
      F4[i,]<-(F3[i]/scale[i])}  #ONLY WANT F3(i) ROW TO BE DIVIDED BY               SCALE(i)  ROW

    > dim(F4)  #DOESN'T GIVE ME 6848x2 Matrix
     [1] 6848    1
```

Comment: Why would element-wise division give you a 6848x2 Matrix?

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a for loop here. Here a vectorized solution:

```
F3/as.vector(sacle) ## BAD! use of built-in function "scale" as a variable!
```

Example :

```
mat <- matrix(1:8,4,2)
sx <- matrix(1:4,4,1)
mat /as.vector(sx)
```

The use of `as.vector` to get-rid of matrix division dimensions.

Comment: agstudy, that worked! thank you! can you explain why you did 1/* and used as.vector(*).